# Do we know anyone from Jonadab?

Tags: jeremiah

I was reading other day Jeremiah 35:18-19

> And to the family of the Rechabites Jeremiah said: “Thus said the
>   Lord of Hosts, the God of Israel: Because you have obeyed the charge
>   of your ancestor **Jonadab** and kept all his commandments, and done all
>   that he enjoined upon you, assuredly, thus said the Lord of Hosts,
>   the God of Israel: There shall never cease to be a man of the line of
>   Jonadab son of Rechab standing before Me.”

and this is got very interesting do we know anything about this family that "God of Israel" promised to keep for ever , it seems similar to the other verse in Jeremiah 33:17

> For thus said the Lord: There shall never be an end to men of **David**’s
>   line who sit upon the throne of the House of Israel.

Is there any significance in this family? how do we understand especially Jeremiah 35:19???

Answer (score 1):

**Significance of Jonadab  family, " other translations "Jehonadab"**

From the verses below we read that Jonadab was in full agreement  ( “Is your heart as true to mine as mine is to yours?”  Jehonadab answered, “It is.”) with King Jehu to wipe out from Israel the worship of Baal and the prophets of Baal. In verse 23 we  read that Jonadab was at the side of Jehu when they entered the temple of Baal during the slaughter of the prophets and worshipers of Baal.

2 Kings 10:15-28 NRSV

> 15 When he left there, he met Jehonadab son of Rechab coming to meet
>   him; he greeted him, and said to him, “Is your heart as true to mine
>   as mine is to yours?” Jehonadab answered, “It is.” Jehu said, “If it
>   is, give me your hand.” So he gave him his hand. Jehu took him up with
>   him into the chariot. 16 He said, “Come with me, and see my zeal for
>   the Lord.” So he[e] had him ride in his chariot. 17 When he came to
>   Samaria, he killed all who were left to Ahab in Samaria, until he had
>   wiped them out, according to the word of the Lord that he spoke to
>   Elijah.

**Slaughter of Worshipers of Baal**

> 18 Then Jehu assembled all the people and said to them, “Ahab offered
>   Baal small service; but Jehu will offer much more. 19 Now therefore
>   summon to me all the prophets of Baal, all his worshipers, and all his
>   priests; let none be missing, for I have a great sacrifice to offer to
>   Baal; whoever is missing shall not live.” But Jehu was acting with
>   cunning in order to destroy the worshipers of Baal. 20 Jehu decreed,
>   “Sanctify a solemn assembly for Baal.” So they proclaimed it. 21 Jehu
>   sent word throughout all Israel; all the worshipers of Baal came, so
>   that there was no one left who did not come. They entered the temple
>   of Baal, until the temple of Baal was filled from wall to wall. 22 He
>   said to the keeper of the wardrobe, “Bring out the vestments for all
>   the worshipers of Baal.” So he brought out the vestments for them. 23
>   Then Jehu entered the temple of Baal with Jehonadab son of Rechab; he
>   said to the worshipers of Baal, “Search and see that there is no
>   worshiper of the Lord here among you, but only worshipers of Baal.” 24
>   Then they proceeded to offer sacrifices and burnt offerings
>
> Now Jehu had stationed eighty men outside, saying, “Whoever allows any
>   of those to escape whom I deliver into your hands shall forfeit his
>   life.” 25 As soon as he had finished presenting the burnt offering,
>   Jehu said to the guards and to the officers, “Come in and kill them;
>   let no one escape.” So they put them to the sword. The guards and the
>   officers threw them out, and then went into the citadel of the temple
>   of Baal. 26 They brought out the pillar[f] that was in the temple of
>   Baal, and burned it. 27 Then they demolished the pillar of Baal, and
>   destroyed the temple of Baal, and made it a latrine to this day.

**

> 28 Thus Jehu wiped out Baal from Israel.

**
**Significance of Jeremiah 35:19**

The other mention of the Rechabites is in Nehemiah 3:14 reads;

> " Malchijah son of Rechab, ruler of the district of[a] Beth-haccherem,
>   repaired the Dung Gate; he rebuilt it and set up its doors, its bolts,
>   and its bars." (NRSV)

This refers to the returned exiles from Babylon  and during the construction and repair of Jerusalem , indicates that God kept his vow,  "There shall never cease to be a man of the line of Jonadab son of Rechab standing before Me.” ( Jeremiah 35:1-19)

Comment: You've nicely connected the (very few!) dots here. There is a lot of [scholarly interest in the Rechabites](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=intitle%3Arechabites) as a perusal of that Google Scholar search will suggest! Much of it has to do with post-biblical developments, however.